# Cannot download pdf using python requests

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests, pypdf

I was able to do this previously, but I think the site might have updated something, and I'm not sure what to change.

```
URL = "https://www.bursamalaysia.com/misc/missftp/securities/securities_equities_2020-12-10.pdf"
r = requests.get(URL, stream = True)
with open(f"{path_to_store_pdfs}/KLSE 2020-12-10.pdf", "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(r.content)
```

When I try to download the data using the above code now, the file appears but there's an error message that says "Adobe Reader could not open … because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged"

My main task is to perform the following code, which also does not work and gives the error "PdfReadError: EOF marker not found".

```
pdf_file = io.BytesIO(r.content)
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

It appears that both problems have to do with the encoding of the pdf, but I'm new to encoding and am not sure if a different encoding was used or a purposely damaged one was used (for detecting bots). Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the request status code. For me, it gives 503 Service Unavailable. Setting the User-Agent fixed it:

```
import requests
user_agent = "scrapping_script/1.0"
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
URL = "https://www.bursamalaysia.com/misc/missftp/securities/securities_equities_2020-12-10.pdf"
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, stream = True)
with open("KLSE 2020-12-10.pdf", "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(r.content)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Will read up more on that, thank you :)