# How do I download all the .hdf files in a webpage using Python?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

```
import requests as rq
r = rq.get('https://opendap.larc.nasa.gov/opendap/CALIPSO/LID_L15-Standard-V1-00/2019/01/contents.html', allow_redirects=True)
open('CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-01T00-25-44ZN.hdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

The code above has helped me download only the first .hdf file in the webpage below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Full working solution

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url='https://opendap.larc.nasa.gov/opendap/CALIPSO/LID_L15-Standard-V1-00/2019/01/contents.html'
req=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
lst=[]
for url in soup.select('tr[itemprop="dataset"] td b a'):
    hdf=url.get('href')
    lst.append(hdf)
    #print(hdf)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['hdf_file'])  # .to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0    CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-01T00-25-44...
1    CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-01T01-11-54...
2    CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-01T02-04-19...
3    CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-01T02-50-29...
4    CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-01T03-42-49...
..                                                 ...
869  CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-31T20-14-08...
870  CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-31T21-06-28...
871  CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-31T21-52-43...
872  CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-31T22-44-58...
873  CAL_LID_L15-Standard-V1-00.2019-01-31T23-31-13...

[874 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: The above code only prints out the names of the links in the webpage of the mentioned URL, it does not the download its data.

Comment: @Ajgar Dev,You can take help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66219052/cannot-download-pdf-using-python-requests]How to download file using requests

Comment: You can use pandas to read all urls to download

Comment: But these links are not URLs, but .hdf files. I guess now the question is that although we have all the names of the .hdf files in a Pandas Dataframe, how do we download each .hdf file whose name is stored in the Pandas Dataframe? The link that you have shared shows an attempt to download a .pdf file.